# Rotate QImage in QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qlistwidget

Got a small app where in a QListWidget many QImage and text are displayed with this function:

```
void TileDisplay::DisplayTiles()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m_tiles.size(); i++) {
        QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem("Tile " + QString::number(i+1), ui->listWidget);
        item->setData(Qt::DecorationRole, m_tiles[i].scaled(64, 64, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation));
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a solution where the QImage is rotated around it's centre with this function:

```
void TileDisplay::RotateImage(int degree)
{
    if(GetTiles().size() > 0) {
        QImage *tileToRotate = GetCurrentTile();
        if(tileToRotate != nullptr) {
            QTransform rotate;
            rotate.rotate(degree);
            tileToRotate->transformed(rotate);
            DisplayTiles();
        }
    }
}
```

It is running without any issue, but the image is not rotated.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#transformed-1) the signature of the `QImage::transformed` member function is...

```
QImage QImage::transformed(const QTransform &matrix, Qt::TransformationMode mode) const;
```

So you need to make use of the returned `QImage`.  Try...

```
*tileToRotate = tileToRotate->transformed(rotate);
```

Comment: Thank you, somehow missed that part.